# List Item ID not appearing in Search Display Template

Tags: 2013, search, display-template

[This blog](http://www.quercussolutions.com/blog/index.php/get-item-id-search-display-template-document-library/) shows a simple example of adding ListItemID to the managed properties in `item_default.html`. I can see the change reflected in `item_default.js` after uploading the html file, but when I put a break point while searching, ctx.CurrentItem does not have the property ListItemID.

In the blog it shows that when you change a display template's managed properties the Result Types needs to be updated. I do not receive this prompt to sync when I alter the display template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah thanks for reminding me about this post.

In order to fix this problem we needed to check a box in the Search Service Application.

Search Schema -> Crawled Properties -> edit the property in question (list item Id, in this case)

Then check the box that says 'Include in full-text index'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way always works for me without go into the central admin and wait for a full crawl is to put 'Line n'{Line n}:'ListItemID' (n can be any number available) in ManagedPropertyMapping. Then go to the front-end UI, edit webpart, change line n to created > Apply > see the result > flip back to ListItemID.

Then you should be able to see the ListItemID

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run a search crawl to populate managed metadata fields. 
Also did you try clean refresh? Display templates are cached as any other .js files.

In regards to display template managed properties, those are also defined in the HTML file, for the following:   .....